# Touch events (touchesMoved) not working on UIViews inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`, and the `UIViewControllers` for those views are not receiving the touch events. If I take the views out of the scroll view then it works.

UserInteraction is default ON of all views but it's still not working!

This must be possible and I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Many Thanks,

Comment: Why don'y you use Gesture recogniser for the same

Comment: I specifically need touchesMoved method call, which gesture would work for this?

Comment: touchesMoved not work in UIScrollView

Comment: @Zeeshan Hope code below will help you

Comment: np @Zeeshan just mark my Answer correct so others can also take advantage :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following code to implementation file then touches moved

```
 @interface UIScrollView(Custom)
    @end
    @implementation UIScrollView(Custom)

   -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
    @end
```

Comment: @Vinodh. Can you also mention, why this has to be done, so that it would be helpful for newbies to understand what is going on.

I believe, when the uiview is added to the scrollview, all the touch events are received by the scrollview and hence the touchesBegan, touchesMoved are not getting called. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following method

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
 [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
 [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
 [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
 [yourView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

And to handle it

```
 -(void)move:(id)sender {

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
         // This will return you location in view
         CGPoint currentPoint =  [sender locationInView:self.view];

         // This will return you location in Scrollview
         CGPoint scrollPoint =  [sender locationInView:[[sender view] superview]];

    }
}
```