# Swift UIScrollView scroll gesture does not call touchesMoved

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I really need `touchesMoved(...)`  method in UIScrollView. I know that there is a method `scrollViewDidScroll(...)`, but I really need the other method.

So I create subclass of UIScrollView and implement those methods.

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    ...
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        print("Move")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("Touch")
    }
}
```

If I click on the scroll view I get (let say I click two times) :

```
Touch
Touch
```

If I click on scroll view and wait a second and then move my finger I get :

```
Touch
Move
Move
```

But then scroller start to scroll and I don't receive anything anymore.
Why scroll gesture doesn't call  those methods?

How do I persuade scroll view to call those methods on scroll?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939503/uiscrollview-and-content-with-requires-touch-move-events

Comment: I don't understand what this question has with mine. I would like to detect scroll, he would like to scroll view with two fingers (not detect them,...).

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259005/uiscrollview-with-touchesmoved-not-called and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541276/touch-events-touchesmoved-not-working-on-uiviews-inside-uiscrollview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect touch position on UiScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762401/detect-touch-position-on-uiscrollview)